# A limit in a Feynman "proof" about Fermat's Theorem.

Tags: integration, limits, physics, mathematical-physics

As perhaps some of you already know, Richard P. Feynman, the famous physicist tried a non-orthodox (in his usual way, I suppose) proof of the Fermat's Last Theorem.

He tried a probabilistic "proof" that no rigurous mathematician in the world would have accepted, but that shows his enormous creativity and insights. It is very well explained here: http://www.lbatalha.com/blog/feynman-on-fermats-last-theorem

I have followed the derivation of Mr. Luis Batalha, but at some point he challenges the reader to prove that the value:

$$c_{n} = \int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}(u^{n} + v^{n})^{-1 + \frac{1}{n}} \, du\,dv $$

when $n \to \infty $ is approximately $1/n$ ($c_{n} \approx 1/n$).

Well, Mr. Batalha says that for big $n$ tends to $1/n$, and I think we can say for $n \to \infty$.

I'm afraid I have tried to solve the limit but I am clueless.

Thank you and congratulations to Mr. Batalha for such an interesting post.

**EDIT:** Typo in the definition of $c_{n}$, the low limit of the integral is 1, not 0 as it was before. I'm afraid the typo is also present in the link.

**EDIT 2:** When I asked this question a few days ago, I couldn't imagine so many rich and fruitful comments and answers. Thank you to all. I am going to let the question open for a few days more if someone wants to continue adding solutions. I think all the comments have been superb. I think I am goingo to choose the answer by @tired. Thank you all.

Comment: very nice link! thanks a lot (+1)

Comment: You're welcome! But all the kudos to Mr. Batalha for his great web post!

Comment: For a proof (i don't have the time to write one for my own) i would really encourage you to use a change of variables $u^n=q^2,v^n=p^2$ and then change to polar coordiantes

Comment: I think there is some error: the integral for $c_n$ does not appear to converge. The problem appears to be in a neighborhood of the origin; I think the transformation from the integral over $x,y>x_0$ was not done correctly in the article. I think the lower limits should instead be $1$ or something like this.

Comment: @Ian: You a re right, check the link in the OP's question, where things are done right. The OP should correct the question.

Comment: @Ian you are right, but it works if you cut out an intervall of length $1/n$ around the origin

Comment: Ah yes, further down in the article they point out this very same typo.

Comment: Since there is not even the slightest hint in the given link, I suggest that L. B. also didn't know how to perform the calculation, and this is why he "invite[s] the readers to derive this limit".

Comment: Ok, guys, I have read you and I have checked the article, and yes, it seems the integral is $\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}(u^{n} + v^{n})^{-1 + \frac{1}{n}} \, du\,dv$. But, does it converge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can give a heuristic derivation of the results found numerically by @RaymondManzoni and @Arentino. I will try to make things more rigorous the next days

First of all we observe the invariance of the integral under the transformation $x \leftrightarrow y$ (i relabel $u\rightarrow x, v\rightarrow y $). 
Therefore we can write by symmetry

$$
I_n=\color{blue}{2}\int_1^{\infty}dx\int_x^{\infty}dy(x^n+y^n)^{-1+1/n}
$$

now setting $(y/x)^n=q$ we obtain

$$
I_n=\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{n}\int_1^{\infty}dx\frac{1}{x^{n-2}}\int_1^{\infty}dq(1+q)^{-1+1/n}q^{-1+1/n}
$$

the integral over $x$ is trivial and yields
$$
I_n=\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{n}\frac{1}{n-3}\int_1^{\infty}dq(1+q)^{-1+1/n}q^{-1+1/n}
$$

the trick now is to recognize that the $n$-dependence of the remaining integral is very weak if $n$ gets big (to be more precise it decreases in powers of $1/n$) so to leading order we may just ignore it
$$
I_n\sim\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{n}\frac{1}{n-3}\int_1^{\infty}dq(1+q)^{-1}q^{-1}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
$$

and therefore

> $$
> I_n\sim\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{n}\frac{1}{n-3}\log(2)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\sim\frac{\color{blue}{2}\log(2)}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
> $$

in agreement with numerical evaluations, and FEYNMAN SEEMS TO BE WRONG ;)

---

**Remark**

By pushing the expansions one step further, i can also confirm Raymonds calculations up to $1/n^3$ so i'm sure now that my method is correct

Comment: Nice! I had the similar idea to substitute $x/y=q$, but without your trick of halving the integration domain that was useless.

Comment: @Aretino ... it also takes quiet some time to figure this out for me...that was a tricky one by any means ^^

Comment: By the way: I think Feynman's general argument is not wrong, because with this behaviour of $c_n$ his reasoning works even better. In other words: he just needed $c_n<k/n$. But the claim $c_n\approx k/n$ for large $n$ is false: I don't know if it was stated as such by Feynman or just by Batalha.

Comment: Neat asymptotic expansion @tired! [Link to p.464](https://books.google.com/books?id=61n5dE7FJQgC&pg=PA464) of Schweber's book and to the [comment 195](https://books.google.fr/books?id=61n5dE7FJQgC&pg=PA658). Erdös and Ulam made too [probabilistic remarks on Fermat's last theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250131729). Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

In terms of polar coordinates, $(u^n+v^n)^{-1+1/n} \leq r^{-n+1} 2^{(-n/2+1)(-1+1/n)} = r^{-n+1} 2^{n/2-3/2+1/n}$. This is attained along $\theta=\pi/4$. This makes geometric sense: the $n$ norms with $n \geq 2$ are smaller than the $2$ norm, and the place where they are smaller by the largest amount is along the lines $y=\pm x$. We're dealing with a negative power of an $n$ norm, so for fixed $r$ it is biggest along those lines.

This looks bad, because of that growing $2^{n/2}$. But you can rewrite this as $2^{-3/2+1/n} r (r/\sqrt{2})^{-n}$. On $[1,\infty) \times [1,\infty)$ you have $r \geq \sqrt{2}$. Thus the integral is bounded by a constant times $\int_1^\infty r^{2-n} dr$. This bound is finite as soon as $n>3$ and behaves like $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$.

I'm not sure whether the original integral is  finite when $n=3$. (Also, I neither claim nor expect that these estimates are at all tight.)

Comment: If $u^n = r^2 \cos^2 t$ and $v^n = r^2 \sin^2 t$, then the Jacobian produces a factor of $(\sin t \cos t)^{\frac 2 n - 1}$. Since the power is negative, the maximum of this expression will be $\infty$, reached in $0$ and $\frac \pi 2$. Or are we maybe talking about different things?

Comment: I was just using $r=(u^2+v^2)^{1/2} $, ordinary polar coordinates.

Comment: @Ian your result is not really correct. you found an upper bound (in a very nice way!) but the asymptotic behaviour is different.

Comment: @tired It's correct, it's just weaker than the strongest possible result. I said this in the last sentence. I will make a minor clarification, though.

Answer (score 3):

The integral can be computed with Mathematica and the result (for $n>3$) is:

$$
\begin{align}
c_n=&{1\over n-3}
\left({4^{-1/n}\over\sqrt\pi} \Gamma\left({1\over2} - {1\over n}\right) 
\Gamma\left({1} + {1\over n}\right)
-{}_2F_1\left({1\over n}, {n-1\over n}; {n+1\over n}; -1\right)\\
+{1\over n-2}\ {}_2F_1\left({n-2\over n}, {n-1\over n}; {2n-2\over n}; -1\right)
\right),\\
\end{align}
$$
where ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

The first term $1/(n-3)$ is nothing but $\int_1^\infty r^{2-n} dr$,
as found by Ian in his answer.
Unfortunately, however, the term in parentheses does not tend to a positive constant for $n\to\infty$, but is rather proportional to $1/n$,
because:

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2c_n
=2\ln2.
$$
It follows that Batalha's claim is false.

Comment: +1: Numerically (using MuPAD) I obtain the same result (for lower limits $1$) : $$c(n)\sim \dfrac {2\ln(2)}{n^2},\quad n\to +\infty$$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I've tried to improve formatting: hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks @Aretino it is! A better asymptotic expression is then : $$c(n)\sim \dfrac {2\ln(2)}{n^2}+\dfrac {\ln(2)(6+\ln(2))+\large{\frac{\pi^2}3}}{n^3},\quad n\to +\infty$$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni rough asymptotic estimates confirm your result 
(besides the factor of $\log2$)

Comment: Thanks for the verification @tired! Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni may i ask if you have a suspecison how to solve this problem rigerously (in an asymtotic sense)

Comment: @tired: Well by proving Aretino's formula $c_n$ right first for example... (I tried this in a numerical/guess way only... yet)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni are you a hundred percent sure about the $2 \log2$? being a little bit more careful with my calculations i find $4/e$ which is quiet close...

Comment: @tired: not a hundred percent but even my next constant (for $\dfrac 1{n^3}$) should be right to at least $100$ digits (I consider the $c_n$ initial mma formula by Aretino with an additional ')' at the end of $(-2+n)$ as exact). Btw feel free to provide your derivation...

Comment: i wait until monday, so i can recheck everything with mathematica. something strange is going on here...

Comment: @tired: Computing $n^2 c_n$ for $n=10^4$ to $18$ digits precision I obtain $1.38708759877404567$ and $1.38708759877403743$ for Aretino's expression and mupad's numerical integral (the second one should be exact). This written I am not sure that Feynman used the lower bound $1$ (doing the symbolic integration 'incorrectly' using polar coordinates with fixed bounds for $r>1$ over a domain thus larger than the rectangle $[1,\infty)\times [1,\infty)$ in $(u,v)$ I obtain $c_n\sim \dfrac 2n,\ n\to\infty$)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni i think i got something...what do you say?

Comment: Indeed, what Raymond is describing is very much like my analysis: I do not take into account that $r=\sqrt{2}$ is only attained at one point of $[1,\infty) \times [1,\infty)$, so that there is a region between the square and the circle where the integrand is considerable, which is excluded in the analysis on $[1,\infty) \times [1,\infty)$.

Comment: i would like to mention that your sum of gammas and hypergeometric should be reduceable to $$(-1)^{2/n}B(-1, 1-2/n, 1/n)/n$$ which looks much more manageble